# Looping in mocha over it()

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, chai

I'd like to iterate over several sets of test files with mocha but my it() never executes.

```
var unitTests = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./test/unitTests.json', 'utf8'));
for (test in unitTests.unitTests) {
  var inputFilename = unitTests.unitTests[test].input;
  console.log(inputFilename);

  it('do stuff with the file', function(done) {
      ...
  });
}
```

My console.log statement does print each input filename but the code inside the it() never executes. If I comment out the loop, it runs just fine.

It seems like I have an incorrect assumption going on here...

How can I look over an it() in mocha?

---

It turns out my original question was wrong.

I was running this in a debugger and I was seeing the console.log statements executing before the it() block executed. I then exited the program. If I let it run my it() blocks run as expected.

It looks like the asynchronous nature of the it() was tripping me up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always wrap your tests in a `describe` block:

```
const fs = require('fs');
var unitTests = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./test/unitTests.json', 'utf8'));

function doStuff(test) {console.log("did stuff with " + test.input)}

describe('runTests', function() {
  unitTests.unitTests.forEach(function(test) {
    it('does stuff with ' + test.input, function(done) {
      var res = doStuff.apply(null, [test]);
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

output of `./node_modules/.bin/mocha test.js`

```
  runTests
did stuff with 1.foo
    ✓ does stuff with 1.foo
did stuff with 4.foo
    ✓ does stuff with 4.foo
did stuff with 3.foo
    ✓ does stuff with 3.foo
did stuff with 2.foo
    ✓ does stuff with 2.foo


  4 passing (8ms)
```

more information: https://mochajs.org/#dynamically-generating-tests

ps. I seeded my `unitTests.json` with

```
{"unitTests": [{"input": "1.foo"},{"input": "4.foo"},{"input": "3.foo"},{"input": "2.foo"}]}
```

Comment: I have a describe block. I'm in a meeting right now but I'll look at your answer right after that ends... Thanks!

Comment: I just edited the question, it turns out my code was working but the asynchronous nature of it() was tripping me up. I'm going to mark yours as the correct answer since you did help me out. Thanks!